# javascript - lightbox image base64 from mysql server

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

So I am trying to add a lightbox functionality. Everything is in working order except for the fact that upon click, the images are in base64 encoding I presume instead of the images themselves. I have already decoded it once in the foreach loop in php, but I don't know how to do it in javascript. The reason why the images are in base64 encoding is because I am storing the images in a mysql database and retrieving  it from there.

I would think it is how you set up the variable "src". Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>Greeting Cards</title>

// css and icons here
  
  /*From website */
<style type="text/css">
    a.fancybox img {
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -o-transform: scale(1,1); -ms-transform: scale(1,1); -moz-transform: scale(1,1); -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); transform: scale(1,1); -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    } 
    a.fancybox:hover img {
        position: relative; z-index: 999; -o-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -ms-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -moz-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -webkit-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); transform: scale(1.03,1.03);
    }
</style>
  
  
</head>

<body>

<!--------Logo------------>
<div id="logo">
<a href="../../index.html" >
<img src="../../icon/icon.png" alt="Our logo picture" >
</a>
</div>
<!------------------------>

/* List of categories */
  
<h2>Greeting Cards</h2>

 <!-------->
<?php
include '/var/db_file.php';
include '/var/www/WideImage/lib/WideImage.php';

$con = mysqli_connect($theDb,$usr, $pass, "images");
mysqli_select_db($con, "images");

$query = "SELECT * FROM Greeting_Cards";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$images = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $images[] = $row['image']; //store raw image
}

echo '<div id ="gallery">';

foreach ($images as $image) {
  $image = WideImage::loadFromString($image)->resize(300, 300); //image resizing here
  echo '<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'"  data-lightbox="roadtrip"> <img id="database" class="fancybox" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" /><a/>'; 
}
echo '</div>';

mysqli_close($con);

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($){
        var addToAll = false;
        var gallery = true;
        var titlePosition = 'inside';
        $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var title = $this.attr('title');
            var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
            var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
            $this.wrap(a);
        });
        if (gallery)
            $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
            titlePosition: titlePosition
        });
    });
    $.noConflict();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I see: Before click:
[image: Before click]

After click: [image: After click]